# Xamarin Studio - change multiple resource ids

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Is there possibility to change multiple Resource IDs in Xamarin Studio ? 
I'm using [SVGImage plugin](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG) and it requires to set SVG files' build action as Embedded Resource and identifies files by it's resource id.

By default when i add files to my project, set it's build action, resource id remains blank which is annoying when i have 255 SVG files containing country flags so is there an option to automate this task?

---

**Working svg file**:

[image]

**Country flag**:

[image]

Comment: How do you use the SVGs to need a resource id? They should have a default resource ID that {project}/{folder(s)}/{filename}, which may be longer but with a helper method you can still find them by the {filename} part. Add some sample of how you're using the image resources please